# Unable to change ANy CPU to x64 or x86

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a website project and in build configuration I am not able to change `Any CPU` to `x64/x86` by clicking on the dropdown and selecting `New`. See image attached. How can I resolve this ?

I am using VS2022. It's a .Net 4.7.2 project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click -> `Active solution platform -> <New...>`

[image]

Choose `x86/x64` from `Type or select the new platform` and click OK.

[image]

We will see `x86/x64` which we can select.

[image]

**EDIT**

if you get the error

> new project platforms cannot be created because this new solution platform is not supported by any of the projects

please uncheck the `Create new project platforms`

[image]

Comment: It says new project platforms cannot be creates because this new solution platform is not supported by any of the projects.

Comment: @Illep I had edited my answer hope that help